# How to update the content of a div when a form is submitted using javaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to update the content of #contentRight when either editForm-1 or editForm-2 is submitted with the submitted form values.

I can get the response output from the updateDB.php file and see it at the

```
alert("Data: " + theResponse + "\nStatus: " + status);
```

However it does not update the div content with either of the following 2 lines.

```
$("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
document.getElementById("contentRight") = theResponse;
```

[EDIT-------------]

I added some styles to see what element is occupying what space. If you click on `#saveEdit-1` (which is the element with the blue border) The script works as it supposed to. When you click on the `#saveEdit-1 button` element (which is the arrow) the div does not get updated. WHY?

[Here is the working example](http://310it.com/test/test.php)

if I change the click listeners to

```
$("#saveEdit-1 button").click(function(){ performAjaxSubmission(1); });
$("#saveEdit-2 button").click(function(){ performAjaxSubmission(2); });
```

it still does not work. [Working Example](http://310it.com/test/test2.php)

[/EDIT-------------]

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Here are the files.

```
<?php   require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #editForm-1, #editForm-2 {
                border:1px solid red;   
            }
            #saveEdit-1, #saveEdit-2 {
                border:2px solid blue;  
            }
            #saveEdit-1 button, #saveEdit-2 button {
                border:3px solid green; 
            }
        </style>

        <link href="/test/stylesheets/_appStyleAdmin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jQuery-UI/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function performAjaxSubmission(formID) {
                // alert(formID);
                var page = "edit-Test";
                var URL = "http://310it.com/test/updateDB.php?page=" + page;
                var formData = $("#editForm-" + formID).serialize();
                // alert(formData);
                $.post(URL , formData, function(theResponse){
                    alert("Data: " + theResponse + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    $("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
                    // $("#contentRight").text(theResponse);
                    //  document.getElementById("contentRight") = theResponse;
                    //  document.getElementById("contentRight").innerHTML(theResponse);
                });                                                              
            }                                 
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){ 

                $("#saveEdit-1").click(function(){ performAjaxSubmission(1); });
                $("#saveEdit-2").click(function(){ performAjaxSubmission(2); });

            }); 
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="contentRight">
            <p>AJAX Response will be displayed here.</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <span></span>
        </div><!-- endof contentRight -->

        <form id="editForm-1" name="editForm-1" method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="edit">
            <input type="hidden" name="formID" id="formID" value="1">
            <div class="addNewItem-InputField">
                <p>Edit Test - 1</p>
                <label for="editTestName"><input type="text" name="editTestName" id="editTestName" /></label>
            </div><!-- endof addNewItem-InputField -->
            <div id="saveEdit-1" name="saveEdit-1" class="submitButton">
                <button title="SAVE EDIT TEST" value="Submit" name="submit" type="submit"><img src="/test/images/icon-update-02.png"></button>
            </div><!-- endof submitButton -->
        </form>

        <p>&nbsp</p>

        <form id="editForm-2" name="editForm-2" method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="edit">
            <input type="hidden" name="formID" id="formID" value="2">
            <div class="addNewItem-InputField">
                <p>Edit Test - 2</p>
                <label for="editTestName"><input type="text" name="editTestName" id="editTestName" /></label>
            </div><!-- endof addNewItem-InputField -->
            <div id="saveEdit-2" name="saveEdit-1" class="submitButton">
                <button title="SAVE EDIT TEST" value="Submit" name="submit" type="submit"><img src="/test/images/icon-update-02.png"></button>
            </div><!-- endof submitButton -->
        </form>

    </body>
</html>


<?php 
/************************************
           updateDB.php
************************************/

if (isset ($_GET['page'])) {
    $currentPage = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $currentPage = NULL;
}
    showVarPre ($_POST);
    showVarMed ($currentPage);      // Shows the current page passed from JS

if  ($currentPage == 'test2') {
    $currentTable = 'records';
} elseif ( $currentPage == 'court-types') {
    $currentTable = 'ota_court_types';
}



$action                 = ($_POST['action']); 
echo "<h3>" . $action . "</h3>";

if ($action == "updateRecordsListings"){

/*
    $listingCounter = 1;
    foreach ($updateRecordsArray as $recordIDValue) {
        $query = "UPDATE " . $currentTable . " SET position = " . $listingCounter . " WHERE id = " . $recordIDValue;
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
        $listingCounter = $listingCounter + 1;  
    }
*/

    echo '<pre>';
    echo '</pre>';
    echo 'If you refresh the page, you will see that records will stay just as you modified.';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using input type as an image rather than using a button with an image. I still do not know or understand why but [here is the related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028840/form-data-submitted-using-jquery-ajax-does-not-update-the-div-content-if-the-s)

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("contentRight").innerHTML(theResponse);
```

Comment: I know that supposed to work, but it does not. Maybe it does change the content of the div, but does not refresh the portion of the window.

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: I did check the console, but there is no errors or warnings. here is the working version [link](http://310it.com/test/test.php)

Comment: I edited the question with some new findings. The script works as it should if you click on the div of the button, but not the button itself. @TateThurston

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting html or text from the response? If it's the former, use:

`$("#contentRight").html(theResponse);`

if it's the later, use:

`$("#contentRight").text(theResponse);`

update:
your form submission is causing a full page refresh. this is the default behavior. you need to catch the event and prevent the default behavior.

```
        `$(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#editForm-1").submit(function(e){ 
                e.preventDefault();
                performAjaxSubmission(1);
            });
            $("#editForm-2").submit(function(e){ 
                e.preventDefault();
                performAjaxSubmission(2);
            });`
```

Comment: also note that you've attached the success function, but currently do not have an error callback. Any AJAX failures will not be reported to the client

Comment: thanks for the heads up, i will deal with the AJAX failures after i get this working.

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately this resulted in preventing even the alert window showing..