# Form data submitted using jQuery/AJAX does not update the <div> content if the submit button is an image

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to show the AJAX response in a div.

It works if I use 'Submit' button, and it does not work if I use an image as a button.

[Here is the working Example of the problem](http://310it.com/test/test-basic.php)

It seems like it should work since it hits the same line in the code and brings back the data. I already spent about 8 hours with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #editForm-1 input{float:left; margin:0 5px; padding:5px; border:1px solid red;  }
            #editForm-1 .imgSubmit {margin:0; padding:0 10px; border:none;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function performAjaxSubmission(formID) {
                var URL = "http://310it.com/test/updateDB-basic.php";
                var formData = $("#editForm-" + formID).serialize();
                $.post(URL , formData, function(theResponse){
                    alert("Data: " + theResponse + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    $("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
                    //  $("#contentRight").text(theResponse);                               //  This WORKS
                    //  document.getElementById("contentRight") = theResponse;              //  This does not work
                    //  document.getElementById("contentRight").innerHTML(theResponse);     //  This does not work
                });                                                              
            }                                 
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="contentRight">
            <p>AJAX Response will be displayed here.</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div><!-- endof contentRight -->

        <form id="editForm-1" name="editForm-1" method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="formID" id="formID" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="edit">
            <label for="editTestName">
                <input type="text" name="editTestName" id="editTestName" />
            </label>
            <input type='button' value='Submit form' title="Submit" onClick='performAjaxSubmission(1)'>
            <input type="image" src="/test/images/icon-update-02.png" class="imgSubmit" title="Submit" onClick='performAjaxSubmission(1)'>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
/************************************
           updateDBbasic.php
************************************/

?><pre><?php
    print_r($_POST);
?></pre>
```

Comment: you aren't preventing the default form submit...page is reloading because of it. Also note that user can submit by keyboard which will bypass your click events and fail ... page will reload and user lost data entered

Comment: Thank you for your comment. i will work on this next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a button with an image tag instead of an input of type image; the latter is a bit buggy.

Change:

```
<input src="/test/images/icon-update-02.png" class="imgSubmit" title="Submit" onclick="performAjaxSubmission(1)" type="image">
```

To:

```
<button style="background-color: #fff" type="button" class="imgSubmit" title="Submit" onclick="performAjaxSubmission(1)">
    <img src="/test/images/icon-update-02.png">
</button>
```

Enjoy (:

Comment: I understand if it does not trigger the click event, but script hits the `alert("Data: " + theResponse + "\nStatus: " + status);` with both options with correct return, but it does not do what it supposed to do in the next line. That was time consuming.